# cakephptime select dropdown not customizable

Tags: css, cakephp, time

i have a time select dropdown in my form in cakephp. When i run the page in chrome, the style of the dropdown is different than the one i get to see when i run the same page in firefox. in firefox i get to see 3 arrow buttons atta ched with each dropdown (autogenerated) as below:
[image]

In chrome i see it differently:

[image]

I wish to hide the arrow buttons in firefox dropdown so that it looks similar to the one in chrome. I googled number of solutions but none worked. This is because cakephp auto generates 3 dropdowns. 
How do i apply  tag in between each of the dropdowns generated?
Code:

```
    <?php
echo $this->Form->input('Rideoffer.DepartureTime', array(
    'type' => 'time',
    'selected' => '9:00:00',
    'interval' => 5
));
?>
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the tags it generates, and generate them manually with whatever type of tags you'd like in/around/before/after them.  Voila.

Remember, CakePHP is just PHP - if it's not making your life easier, just bypass that part and do it in "normal" PHP/HTML way.

(I don't believe you can specify via FormHelper a separator tag/code for auto-generated date-time dropdowns)